# How can i pass over a directory or a file that is access denied when searching?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried to add try and catch bit it didn't help it's just stop and nothing happen.
I see the form1 and it finish after less then a second. Something is wrong with the try and catch.
How can i pass over a directory or a file that are access denied ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Search_Text_In_Files
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"e:\textresults.txt");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FindLines(@"E:\", "Green");
        }

        public List<string> FindLines(string DirName, string TextToSearch)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            List<string> findLines = new List<string>();
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(DirName);
            if (di != null && di.Exists)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    {
                        if (string.Compare(fi.Extension, ".cs", true) == 0)
                        {
                            using (StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText())
                            {
                                string s = "";
                                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
                                    if (s.Contains(TextToSearch))
                                    {
                                        counter++;
                                        findLines.Add(s);
                                        listView1.Items.Add(fi.Name);
                                        w.WriteLine("File Name: " + fi.Name);
                                        w.WriteLine("File Name Line: " + s);
                                        w.WriteLine(" ");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ee)
                {

                }
                w.Close();
            }
            return findLines;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `try...catch` is to handle the exception not for avoiding exception. if you need to handle the occurred exception write necessary codes in the catch

Comment: Swallowing exceptions with empty `catch` block is not recommended, you will never come to know if there was anything wrong with the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the ACL (Access Control List) / AuthorizationRuleCollection of the Path.

You need to walk through the "FileSystemAccessRules" and accumulate what's allowed and denied.  Then interpret if the user is a member of that group for each rule.  This should get you started:

```
//using System.Security.AccessControl;  
//using System.Security.Principal;


private bool CheckForAccess(string PathName)
{
    // Determine if the path is a file or a directory

    if (File.Exists(PathName) == true)
        return CheckFileForAccess(PathName);

    if (Directory.Exists(PathName) == true)
        return CheckFolderForAccess(PathName);

    return false;
}


private bool CheckFileForAccess(string FileName)
{
    FileSecurity fs = new FileSecurity(FileName, AccessControlSections.Access);
    if (fs == null)
        return false;

    AuthorizationRuleCollection TheseRules = fs.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
    if (TheseRules == null)
        return false;

    return CheckACL(TheseRules);
}

private bool CheckFolderForAccess(string FolderName)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(FolderName);
    if (di == null)
        return false;

    DirectorySecurity acl = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
    if (acl == null)
        return false;

    AuthorizationRuleCollection TheseRules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
    if (TheseRules == null)
        return false;

    return CheckACL(TheseRules);
}

private bool CheckACL(AuthorizationRuleCollection TheseRules)
{
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule ThisRule in TheseRules)
    {
        if ((ThisRule.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.Read) == FileSystemRights.Read)
        {
            if (ThisRule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
                return false;
        }
        // Run as many other checks as you like
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Don how do i use the CheckForAccess in my code ? I'm getting the access denied exception on the foreach line: foreach (FileInfo fi in di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))

Comment: Check the directory for access BEFORE calling EnumerateFiles

Comment: But then it will be the main directory only. What about the sub directories ?

Comment: You need to check each folder and file in which you will be accessing BEFORE you access it.  Start with the parent root folder.  Your program, when running under reduced rights, might not have rights even to read the root folder.  Also you need may need to adjust the AccessControlType depending upon what your going to do.

Comment: So i added now just before the foreach: if (CheckFileForAccess(DirName) == true) but then it's trying to make the foreach and then i get the exception on the 'in' the exception :  Access to the path 'E:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-' is denied so it passed the root directory DirName but then in the foreach in one of the sub directories it access denied.

Comment: It's likely because your using DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles() which needs security rights to get the info.
Instead try using Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(); to get the string of each file/folder and then check for access before getting the Info.  Also I updated the code in my answer slightly in case you had not noticed.